# how do i know when someone says 他 or 她 in a conversation?

Tags: word-choice, meaning-in-context

她 means she, and 他 which means he, (they a are both pronounced ta) how can I tell the difference between the two in a conversation without any writing.

Comment: That is why, in everyday conversation, unless the context is clear or everyone knows who they are referring to, people don't just say "Ta" and leave it hanging and expect the listener to guess. An alternative, in a colloquial, informal setting, is to say 那个家伙, (that fellow), to mean a male and 那个女士, (Miss or Ms.), for female. In English, "that person" is similarly imprecise, requiring further clarification.

Answer (score 1):

No. We can't distinguish whether it refers to a male or female if we don't know the subject.

You can only figure it out through the subject of the conversation and identifying who is subjected to the reference - Mary or John.....

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have to guess it from the context, maybe the person will mention the name of the person you are speaking about.